# Visualize RNA co-folded secondary structure with Python

Tags: python, visualization, rna, secondary-structure, jupyter

I would like to visualize the secondary structure of co-folded RNA strands in Python, preferably in a Jupyter notebook.
What are the recommended tools? Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

... . I know both aspects of this question and I'm not aware of an interactive Python package using e.g. iPython magic commands that will do this. The thing you could try is  `draw_RNA` https://github.com/DasLab/draw_rna

`draw_RNA` will operate on Jupyter, but I've not tried it.

A very, very good package is [VARNA](https://varna.lri.fr) (its Java BTW). The `VARNA` group make further recommendations from there for complex structures. I would vouch for this package for complex structures.

A good approach is to output in Stockholm 1.0 format. It then just drops and drags into `VARNA`. `Dot-bracket` format also works and I would assume `ct` format works too.

A good reason why in-line graph imaging isn't the best solution for complex structures, i.e. the in-line graphs in a Python debugger or Jupiter is complex RNA structures need to be interactive because you need to move them: they "clump" together and have to manually separate them.

As a final note [Forna](http://rna.tbi.univie.ac.at/forna/) may be of benefit,